# Freeing struct sk_buff (not freeing behavior)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Writing `ndo_start_xmit()` NIC driver function assume that after data transmission I **must** call `dev_kfree_skb()` of consumed `struct sk_buff` and return `NETDEV_TX_OK`.

What should I expect if consumed `struct skb` will not be freed up during module lifetime?

Can Linux kernel free `struct sk_buff` after some timeout or in another way?

Are there difference of behavior between various versions of Linux kernel?

---

[Linux kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/driver.html) mentioned in the topic:

> An ndo_start_xmit method must not modify the shared parts of a cloned
> SKB.
>
> Do not forget that once you return NETDEV_TX_OK from your
> ndo_start_xmit method, it is your driver’s responsibility to free up
> the SKB and in some finite amount of time.
>
> For example, this means that it is not allowed for your TX mitigation
> scheme to let TX packets “hang out” in the TX ring unreclaimed forever
> if no new TX packets are sent. This error can deadlock sockets waiting
> for send buffer room to be freed up.
>
> If you return NETDEV_TX_BUSY from the ndo_start_xmit method, you must
> not keep any reference to that SKB and you must not attempt to free it
> up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, drivers will typically follow some variant of this flow:

1. In `.ndo_start_xmit`:

   1. Setup a DMA:able mapping to the `skb`s data
   2. Fill in a descriptor with a pointer to that data
   3. Let the hardware know that new descriptors are available for transmission
   4. Store a reference to the `skb`-to-be-transmitted in an internal list
2. Some time later - either from a napi poll callback or in an IRQ handler, walk through all descriptors that have been marked as transmitted, and for each one:

   1. Fetch the corresponding `skb` from the internal list and free it.
   2. Tear down the DMA mapping.

In other words, the kernel does not provide any guardrails here. The responsibility lays solely on you. This is because the kernel has no way of knowing when your hardware is done with it.

To properly handle the case of module unloading, your driver must ensure that all tx rings are cleaned when the netdev is unregistered (i.e. performing step 2 above).

This basic division of responsibilities has not changed at all for as long as I've been doing Linux network drivers (10+ years).

My interpretation of the docs you've cited is:

> Dear driver writer: You may be tempted to only enable a Tx IRQ on every 256:th descriptor as a performance optimization to batch your cleanup work - don't do that! Because if you do, I (the kernel) may incorrectly determine that I need to apply backpressure on the associated sockets if no other transmissions are taking place.

I.e. you may think "I don't mind having 255 outstanding `skb`s - I have plenty of RAM to spare". Well, consider this case:

1. You're on a box with a single open socket with a send buffer size (wmem) of 128k
2. The socket receives 128 1k-sized buffers and queues them for transmission
3. The socket can't send any more data until the underlying `skb`s have been freed - but they won't be freed until another 128 are sent to the NIC
4. Deadlock

Comment: Thank's!  But I would to know what happens if I will not freed up `struct skb`? How long these `struct skb`-s will be live in kernel memory? Is the **timeout** or time-to-live of kernel-allocated `struct skb`-s? My colleague strictly claim that in Centos 7.5 kernel `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` there is timeout for `struct skb` live.  This phrase  from kernel documentation he explained as timeout present:  **in some finite amount of time**. I'm confused but still sure that there is no timeout.

Comment: I think the documentation says to "free up the SKB and [do it] in some finite amount of time". Not that in some finite amount of time the kernel will take care of it. They want you to do it otherwise it will live infinitely.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk: Can your colleague provide a link to the source where that timeout is implemented? I also added my interpretation of the kernel docs to my answer.

Comment: @wkz Thank you! I think so. I told to my colleague about proofs but he avoids it. Currently I'm analyzing CentOS kernel code and find that it has some difference between vanilla 3.10 Linux kernel source. In first look `dev_hard_start_xmit()` function in CentOS has completely different approach than in vanilla Linux kernel. I don't believe that these difference can impact on global NIC driver implementation approach but I need to be sure.

Comment: @wkz I've analyzed CentOS 7.5 `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` kernel source about freeing `struct skb`. I've made sure that **kernel doesn't freedup `struct skb` by self in some specific time or timeout**. At the same time my colleague have found bug of twice freeing `struct skb`. So that is it. Thank you for your help and explanation!